# Countour Integration

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, contour-integration

I had to evaluate this integral $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x \sin(x)}{x^2 - b^2}dx  $, according to Wolfram this had the following result $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x \sin(x)}{x^2 - b^2}  dx= \pi e^{ib}$$

However, when I integrated it:

$$\oint_C f(z) dz = \oint_{\gamma_{1}} f(z) dz + \oint_{\gamma_{2}} f(z) dz + \oint_{\Gamma} f(z) dz $$

The last term goes to zero applying Jordan's Lemma and to get the result of the integral over $\gamma_{1}$ and $\gamma_{2}$, in which $\gamma_{1}$ is the contour over the first pole and $\gamma_{2}$ is the contour over the second pole.

So, I get  $$\oint_{\gamma_{1}} f(z) dz = i \pi  \lim_{z \rightarrow -b} \frac{z \sin(z)}{(z-b)(z+b)}(z+b) =  i \pi \frac{\sin(-b)}{-2} $$

and

$$\oint_{\gamma_{2}} f(z) dz = i \pi  \lim_{z \rightarrow b} \frac{z \sin(z)}{(z-b)(z+b)}(z-b) =  i \pi \frac{\sin(b)}{2} $$

The result that I'm getting is:

$$\oint_C f(z) dz = i \pi \left( \frac{\sin(b)}{2} - \frac{\sin(-b)}{-2} \right) = \frac{\pi}{2} \left( e^{ib} - e^{-ib} \right)$$

That according to Wolfram is not the correct result.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

In this case, I used $$f(z) = \frac{z \sin(z)}{z^2 - b^2}$$

Edit 2:
[image]

Edit 3:

Using @Ted Shifrin 's suggestion to change $f(z)$ to a more well-behaved function when $|z|$ is very large, I got:

$f(z) = \frac{z \exp(iz)}{z^2 - b^2}$

So, I get  $$\oint_{\gamma_{1}} f(z) dz = i \pi  \lim_{z \rightarrow -b} \frac{z \exp(iz)}{(z-b)(z+b)}(z+b) =  i \pi \frac{\exp(-ib)}{2} $$

and

$$\oint_{\gamma_{2}} f(z) dz = i \pi  \lim_{z \rightarrow b} \frac{z \exp(iz)}{(z-b)(z+b)}(z-b) =  i \pi \frac{\exp(ib)}{2} $$

The result that I'm getting is:

$$\oint_C f(z) dz = i \pi \left( \frac{\exp(ib)}{2} + \frac{\exp(-ib)}{2} \right) = i \pi \cos(b)$$

and in conclusion:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x \sin(x)}{x^2 - b^2}dx = \Im(i \pi cos(b)) = \pi \cos(b) $$

I still don't understand, according to some of you this integral doesn't converge how do I prove that?

This result is equal to @FelixMarin 's result and he used another method of integration, but is different of Wolfram's result and assuming that $b \in \Re $ this integral is supposed to diverge. What am I missing?

Comment: What are $\gamma_1$, $\gamma_2$, and $\Gamma$? You need to pick specific contours that are relevant to the original integral; it's not enough to have abstract contours that one can evaluate in the limit. Here, when you pick specific contours, you'll realize that only one of the two poles of the integrand is contained in the contour. (You can arrange the contour to contain either pole, but the integrand will be slightly different, and you should get the same answer in both cases.)

Comment: As I said in the post, $\gamma_{1}$ and  $\gamma_{2}$ are contours as small as I want  around each pole.

Comment: You've successfully evaluated those contour integrals, but they in and of themselves have nothing to do with the original problem. In other words, you invented an object $\oint_C f(z) \,dz$ and evaluated it; what does that have to do with $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \,dx$?

Comment: In my complex analysis class, whenever I need to evaluate a real integral that is too complicated to do it by real methods, we extend the problem to the complex plane and use the following correspondence $$\oint_{C} f(z) dz = \int_{\infty}^{\infty}f(x)  dx + \oint_{\Gamma} f(z) dz$$, where the last term goes to zero in this case. Am I missing something?@GregMartin

Comment: Did you tell us what your $f(z)$ was? You should know by now that using $\sin z$ or $\cos z$ will be very problematic for control when $|z|$ is large.

Comment: I edited the post! @TedShifrin

Comment: Yes, good, but did you stop to think about my comment? You need a different choice of $f(z)$. Look at how your textbook does basic integrals like $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ by contour integration.

Comment: In cases of integrals like that , we use $f(z) = \frac{exp(iz)}{z}$ and then take the real or imaginary part. I should the same we this integral? Due to the reason that $sin(z)$ and $cos(z)$ are very difficult to control when $|z!$ is large?@TedShifrin

Comment: As stated, the integral doesn't converge for $b>0$. Don't you mean $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x\sin x}{x^2+b^2}dx=\pi e^{-|b|}$ for $b\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$?

Comment: I'm going to add a screenshot of Wolfram's result @J.G.

Comment: @RFeynman You mean the one that requires $\Im b>0$? [I raise you what I had in mind](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x*sin%28x%29%2F%28x%5E2-1%29+from+-inf+to+inf).

Comment: Yeah, It gotta be like that. Honestly, in class I had the same doubt we need that condition to make the integral non-divergent, but the professor didn't it impose it and got some result.

Comment: $$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{x \sin (x)}{x^2-b^2} \, dx$$ doesn't converge for real $b$. Plot the function and you'll see the reason why

Comment: That was what I said to the professor, but he wasn't convinced. how can I prove by residue integration or by any analytical tool that this integral doesn't converge?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\left.\mrm{P.V.}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{x\sin\pars{x} \over x^{2} - b^{2}}\,\dd x
\,\right\vert_{\,b\ \in\ \mathbb{R}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\,\mrm{P.V.}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\sin\pars{x} \over x + b}\,\dd x +
{1 \over 2}\,\mrm{P.V.}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\sin\pars{x} \over x - b}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\,\mrm{P.V.}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\sin\pars{x - b} + \sin\pars{x + b} \over x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\,\mrm{P.V.}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{2\sin\pars{x}\cos\pars{b} \over x}\,\dd x =
\bbx{\pi\cos\pars{b}} \\ &
\end{align}

Comment: woah! nice solution as usual Felix (+1)

Comment: Honestly, I don't agree with your answer. If $b \in \R$ the integral doesn't converge, has said by other users in the comments, using comparison test we see that $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x sin(x)}{x^2 - b^2} > \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2} $$ and the integral on $  \frac{1}{x^2} $ diverges, so does the integral on $\frac{x sin(x)}{x^2 - b^2}$.                                                                                                                   Aside from that, I got the same result as you, even though is different than Wolfram's result,

Comment: @RFeynman That's where the [principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) $\text{P.V.}$ comes in. It's an improper integral, but by applying the $\text{P.V.}$ we can treat it as a finite quantity

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you very much!

Comment: @RFeynman ${\tt Matematica}$: 
$\verb*ClearAll[b, x]; Integrate[
 x Sin[x]/(x^2 - b^2),*$
$\verb*{x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> Element[b, Reals], *$
$\verb*PrincipalValue -> True]*$. $\quad\color{red}{\mbox{Result}}$: $\verb*\[Pi] Cos[b]*$

Comment: @RFeynman In your question, you don't define $b$ as a Complex Number. So, I assumed $b \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @clathratus Thanks. It's the solution for $b \in \mathbb{R}$.